# Matlab Spearman Correlation PVAL = 0?

Tags: matlab, correlation, p-value

I am conducting Spearman's Correlation with two data sets with 300 objects. These are my variables and commands:

```
a = [1:300]
b = [1 2 5 11 9 7 24 10 31 23 3 40 6 17 14 20 16 12 33 46 70 37 87 43 98 26 59 58 77 100 35 42 78 80 243 36 33327 4 83 160 163 198 86 94 406 111 28 29 55 113 239 295 110 196 177 32679 229 342 305 300 254 96 210 514 167 172 232 190 117 32081 25 158 19333 241 82 149 159 66 178 24487 68 30 1016 725 266 391 638 348 320 681 242 319 228 381 408 442 202 369 471 821 191 426 8 270 211 2266 619 576 441 680 3431 1167 723 74 318 556 640 395 1059 579 614 212 325 437 323 687 373 599 26637 985 54 84 802 724 154 417 240 1120 818 2309 462 109 104 509 494 427 57 2475 549 396 419 123 580 79 225 1132 351 76 16859 596 862 315 470 992 257 120 409 751 832 285 1534 714 1665 1376 2129 678 416 721 209 31971 183 356 1346 1015 1003 188 1076 1634 608 1056 338 308 145 418 625 1313 121 2484 996 783 329 1185 697 157 1100 175 622 235 456 277 166 2700 1439 461 653 433 540 1191 234 774 1894 1004 741 1062 948 48 99 405 797 237 1104 2286 22620 1429 30672 1808 169 458 22 1115 10660 872 474 1063 88 1727 1017 1107 1398 1519 703 1092 1027 272 263 1152 1770 1099 507 385 2118 19356 1778 2458 410 2110 7522 17166 4065 15136 13294 10876 17174 2434 9898 5663 13594 10506 11552 15635 9322 3223 8949 12388 13216 13851 13852 6696 12177 4700 17199 2067 11110 15486 5664 6593 4701 527 8616 268]



    [RHO,PVAL] = corr(b',a','Type', 'Spearman')

RHO =

    0.6954


PVAL =

     0
```

Out of the 5 comparisons I made with other data sets of 300 objects, only 1 returned significant P-values. Is there an explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a different data set and got a value that was not significant (PVAL > 0.05). I also displayed the answer in a long (15 digits) and exponential form and got 0.00000000000000e+000 using:

```
format longEng
```

I also checked with another statistics program that reported the p-value as < 0.0001. This means that the p-value is just really, really small.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know! Figured as the data set objects increased it would become more significant.